# USB dongle (MTS MBlaze) doesn't mount

Tags: usb, mount

I bought an `MTS MBlaze ultra` USB dongle.

There is a manual that came with it.
It asks me to plug it in, and find a `media/cdrom0` directory and run a script in it.

But I can't find `cdrom0` or anything like that under `/media/`.

What should I do?

Output of `dmesg | tail` :

```
[   50.708749] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   50.708750] option: v0.7.2:USB Driver for GSM modems
[   51.700859] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFFE 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   51.701714] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   51.703415] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   80.999316] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 160d0000, was 16000000
[  108.993405] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[  109.051205] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
[  328.405235] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 000d0000, was 160d0000
[  340.306966] cfg80211: Found new beacon on frequency: 2467 MHz (Ch 12) on phy0
```

**EDIT : output of same command on another identical device:**

```
[20200.396232] option 2-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[20200.396448] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[20200.396681] option 2-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[20200.396891] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[20200.397090] option 2-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[20200.397270] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[20200.397674] scsi15 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.4
[20201.393856] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFFE 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[20201.394677] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[20201.396164] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: When you plugin the MTS mblaze,a disk like icon will appers on the unity.Open it.It contains mts linux driver files.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, no. Nothing appears. Like I said it doesn't even mount. It would appear only if it mounted.

Comment: Open gparted and find the mts partition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I can't find it there either.

Comment: If it was there,then run the command to manually mount it `sudo mount /dev/sd(according to your partition)`

Comment: open gparted and select the dev/sda in top right corner,a drop down list appears.from that select your mblaze partition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `/dev/sda` is the only entry in that drop down.

Comment: see `mts mblaze` was there after running this command `lsblk`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I don't it find it there either. But I must tell you that I can use my MTS for internet, but not as a USB device. I followed these instructions to configure it for internet: http://jaiswalayush.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-mts-mblaze-on-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: @AvinashRaj, what do you think might be the issue? Did something stated in that link cause this issue? I need the USB to be detected to install the GUI and to safely remove my dongle without damaging it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, the driver isn't the issue for me. I can use the internet. But I just need to be able to safely remove the device.

Comment: what was the output of `lsblk`,is there you find any mts mblaze partition in that.If yes then run this command `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1`.What was your disks utility shows?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `lsblk` doesn't show any "MTS".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error message, your system is attempting to mount the device but the device is either drawing to much power from your system, or is wired wrong. If you have bought the device recently I would return it and try to get a new one. If you have made it, check your wiring. This problem has happened to me a few times, my logs looked pretty much the same.

Comment: I'll try it out in another device of the same kind (my friend has one) and let you know how it goes...

Comment: Please can you look at my edit? I tried the same thing on another device.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like kernal issues.Try to update your kernal,it may solve your problem.Run the below command to update your kernal,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

After that reboot your pc.

Comment: Nope, a kernel update didn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me with a Reliance dongle.

What I did for it:

just open the device on windows and on windows it will mount the device properly so that you can view the files inside the device now copy the files on another normal pendrive and 
just copy these files from the pendrive to your ubuntu...

Now you can install the GUI from these files(**I guess they provide an installation script**) and as you say that you are able to use internet from this dongle it should not create any other issue..

This trick worked for me..but still I don't know the problem with auto mounting the device.

***I think it tries to run a script at mounting time which ubuntu does not allow(for security reasons but windows do!)***

hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. I could see the drive on Windows, the very first time before I installed the MTS MBlaze software. After that I can't find the storage drive there. Maybe I should uninstall it again.